# How can I merge a list of tuples into a single tuple?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm trying to iterate through a list of tuples and return a single value. For example:

```
[(5, "Cat"), (5, "Dog"), (5, "Horse")]
```

And I want to return a tuple that only combines the second spot in the tuples together, so the end result would be:

```
(5, "CatDogHorse")
```

I'm stuck on how to do this. I've tried using [list comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension) and just getting the first index of the resulting list, but I can't find a way to just add the second item to a single variable that I can return.

Comment: Do you want to group by the first integer? E.g. should `[(1, "Cat"), (2, "Dog"), (1, "Horse"), (2, "Donkey")]` result in `[(1, "CatHorse"), (2, "DogDonkey")]`?

Comment: @bereal Na, I only want to return one tuple that merges all tuple second elements together from a list (5, "CatDogHorse")

Comment: Please click on edit and update your question to clarify what the first element of your result tuple should look like.

Comment: The subject of meta question *[Should questions where OP replaces their question with vandalism be flagged?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/411652)*.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you don't care about the first element of the tuple, and it's ok to keep the first of them, the most straightforward way is using [`foldr1`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr1) with concatenation:

```
join = foldr1 $ \(x, y) (_, z) -> (x, y ++ z)
```

For 3-tuples it's similar:

```
join3 = foldr1 $ \(a, b, c) (_, _, d) -> (a, b, c ++ d)
```

Update: I see that [point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree) is new for you, so the here are the same definitions with explicit arguments:

```
join xs = foldr1 (\(x, y) (_, z) -> (x, y ++ z)) xs
join3 xs = foldr1 (\(a, b, c) (_, _, d) -> (a, b, c ++ d)) xs
```

Comment: Would this also work with 3-tuples and arbitrarily long lists?

Comment: @BBQSquirrel for 3-tuples you'd have to write a separate, but similar function. This should handle arbitrary long lists.

Comment: Does this actually return a type of the tuple though? Because I get this error:

```Couldn't match expected type ‘(Int, Int, String)’ with actual type ‘t0 (t1, t2, [a0]) -> (t1, t2, [a0])’ In the expression: foldr1 $ \ (x, y, z) (_, _, a) -> (x, y, z ++ a)```

When using = foldr1 $ \(x, y, z) (_, _, a) -> (x, y, z ++ a)

Comment: @BBQSquirrel you seem to be passing a single tuple instead of a list of tuples.

Comment: This is my code atm

```combineList :: [(Int, Int, String)] -> (Int, Int, String)
combineList xs = foldr1 $ \(x, y, z) (_, _, a) -> (x, y, z ++ a)
```

Comment: Surely this wouldn't work in this case? I have no way to directly access each element of the tuple, i only have the list xs of tuples?

Comment: @BBQSquirrel You define `combineList` with an argument `xs`, which you don't need, because it's in point-free form. I have updated the answer with the 3-tuples version.

Comment: I don't understand, what should the arguement be then for combineList?

Comment: @BBQSquirrel there's no argument, it's [Point-free style](https://wiki.haskell.org/Pointfree). I'll update the answer.